# Why does a piece of code gets executed or not at random?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

Generally I have this map generation code, then I divide the map into two sectors and then each one into two more.

I have been trying to mark the first pair of sectors into my map, but for some reason, first sector is marked nicely, and then the double for loop for the second sector is sometimes executed, and sometimes not.

The piece of code:

```
Sector root = new Sector(0, 0, width, height);
Sector levelOne[] = root.divideSector(' ');
System.out.println("LevelOneA: (" + levelOne[0].getOriginX() + ", " + levelOne[0].getOriginY() + ") : " + levelOne[0].getWidth() + "x" + levelOne[0].getHeight());
for (int y = levelOne[0].getOriginY(); y < levelOne[0].getHeight(); y++){
    for (int x = levelOne[0].getOriginX(); x < levelOne[0].getWidth(); x++){
        insertMapPoint(new Point(x, y, "sector one"));
        System.out.println("exe");
    }
}
System.out.println("LevelOneB: (" + levelOne[1].getOriginX() + ", " + levelOne[1].getOriginY() + ") : " + levelOne[1].getWidth() + "x" + levelOne[1].getHeight());
for (int y = levelOne[1].getOriginY(); y < levelOne[1].getHeight(); y++){
    for (int x = levelOne[1].getOriginX(); x < levelOne[1].getWidth(); x++){
        insertMapPoint(new Point(x, y, "sector two"));
    }
}
```

All the System.out.prinln() functions work properly, all data displayed is correct, but the second pair of for loops (the ones for LevelOneB) is the one that I have problems with.

The code is not relying on anything else. This is the screenshot of the result I'm talking about, please note that I put a call to print "exe" as a testing means to see if the second pair is being executed.

[image]

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: There is nothing random about this. You may want to learn to understand code first.
for instance: for (int y = levelOne[1].getOriginY(); y < levelOne[1].getHeight(); y++){
if y is larger than levelOne[1].getHeight() from the start, this loop will never be executed.

Comment: Your loop is `for (int y = 12, y < 8, y++)`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I got stuck in the loophole, forgot to add the originX/Y values to the limitation.

Comment: You should provide the answer and mark this question as answered, please.